# Python - File size finder - Error when walking through directory tree (OSError: WinError 1920 - [...] GameBarElevatedFT_Alias.exe)

Tags: python, windows

I wrote a little bit of code that prints the paths of files whose sizes are bigger than X bytes.

```
import os

path = 'C:\\'

print("Starting...")

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        filepath = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
        if os.path.getsize(filepath) > 1e+10:               # 1 GB = 1e+9 | 10 GB = 1e+10
            try:
                print(filepath)
            except OSError:
                print("An OSError occurred.")

print("Finished.")
```

It works great on my `D:` drive, but unfortunately not on my `C:`. On my `C:`, I get the following error message:

OSError: WinError 1920 - System cannot access file: 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\GameBarElevatedFT_Alias.exe'

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I solve this?
3. Why doesn't my `try...except` print "An OSError occurred." when it comes across this file and continue with the next `filename`?

PS: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: The try...except isn't going to catch it because the error is occuring on `os.path.getsize` which is outside the try block.  As far as 'why', could be many reasons; permissions, corrupt file, invalid pathspec, etc.

Comment: Thanks, you were right! I put the `if` in the `try` block and now it works.